# I am unable to retrieve gmail emails from any other labels other than inbox/sent/starred using IMAP library python version 3.9.12

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap

I'm unable to retrieve gmail emails from any other labels other than inbox/sent/starred using imap library.

I am using 3.9.12 python version.

- This is working

```
imap.select("Inbox")
```

- This is working

```
imap.select('"[Gmail]/Starred"')
```

- This is working

```
imap.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
```

- This isnot working giving error [('NO', [b'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/Labels/BI report (Failure)'])
  ]

```
imap.select('"[Gmail]/Labels/BI report"')
```

Anyone please suggest how to retrieve email from different gmail lables other than inbox/sent/starred.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692144/python-imaplib-cant-select-custom-gmail-labels

Comment: @tripleee, that answer is about quoting, and OP has labels quoted already.

Comment: Yeah, but it also suggests that the `select` should name _just_ the label. I don't use Gmail so I can't check.

Comment: You should run a "LIST" command to see what the actual name is.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

```py
imap.select("\"" + "Label Name" + "\"")
```

Thanks